# Возврат из условного оператора

Tags: c#

Как вернуться из условного оператора else к вводу года, если пользователь ввел вместо цифр символы или буквы? При этом выдать сообщение, что были введены символы. т.е. своеобразную обработку исключения. 
Пробовал через try\catch, но программа все равно прерывается.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите год: ");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int year;

        // Проверяем, что введенное значение можно преобразовать в целочисленный тип.
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out year))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Текущий год: " + year);
        }
        else 
        {
            // Хочу выдать ошибку сообщением и вернуться к вводу года.
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Int32.TryParse` работает без исключений.

```
while (true)
{
  Console.Write("Введите год: ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  int year;
  if (Int32.TryParse(input, out year))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Текущий год: " + year);
    break;
  }
  else 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error. Try again.");
  }
}
```